# Find $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z_k^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning

Let $z_1, z_2,\dots, z_k,\dots$ be all the roots of $e^z=z$.

Let $C_N$ be the square in the plane centered at the origin with siden parallel to the axis and each of length $2\pi N$.

Assume that $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \int\limits_{\displaystyle C_N}\frac{e^z-1}{z^2(e^z-z)}dz=0$$

Find $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z_k^2}$$

---

My solution attempt is too trivial. So I didn't write it here. Please, solve the question more explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: How is the integral related with the sum?

Comment: In fact, I dont know @DanielFischer

Comment: Ah, but that's the key. What is generally $$\int_{C_N} f(z)\,dz\;?$$

Comment: Its limit converges to the sum. Right? @danielFischer

Comment: The integral is equal to $2\pi i \sum Res(f, z_k)+2\pi i\sum Res(f, 0)$ right? @DanielFischer

Comment: Right, that's it.

Comment: And then? @DanielFischer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us call $f(z) = e^z - z$. Then the integral can be written

$$\int_{C_N} \frac{f'(z)}{z^2 f(z)}\,dz.$$

If $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus D$, where $D$ is a closed discrete set in $\mathbb{C}$, then

$$\int_{C_N} g(z)\,dz$$

is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $g$ in the points of $D$ that are enclosed by $C_N$ (provided none of the points of $D$ lies on the contour $C_N$).

Here, the integrand $\dfrac{f'(z)}{z^2 f(z)}$ has singularities in the $z_k$ and in $0$. The residue in $z_k$ is $\dfrac{1}{z_k^2}$ since $f$ has only simple zeros, so

$$\int_{C_N} \frac{f'(z)}{z^2 f(z)}\,dz =  2\pi i \left(\operatorname{Res} \left(\frac{f'(z)}{z^2f(z)}; 0\right) + \sum_{z_k \in S_N} \frac{1}{z_k^2}\right).$$

Since the integral tends to $0$ for $N\to \infty$, we obtain

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z_k^2} = -\operatorname{Res} \left(\frac{f'(z)}{z^2f(z)}; 0\right).$$

It remains to find that residue. Since $f(0) = 1$, we need the residue of $\dfrac{e^z-1}{z^2}$ in $0$, which is easily seen to be $1$.